# Como tira bordas de tabela PrimeFaces?

Tags: xhtml, primefaces-3.5

Saudações para todos,

sou novo como programador Java, e estou trabalhando na parte de programação Frond-End de um projeto JSF2, mas estou tendo dificuldade para tira as bordas de uma tabela como você observa a baixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está as linhas de código da pagina XHTML;

```
<div class="left-sidebar">

    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel1"
            style="width: 50%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
            <p:outputLabel value="SKU" for="sku" />
            <p:inputText id="sku" size="20" maxlength="20" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome" />
            <p:inputText id="nome" size="20" maxlength="20" />
        </p:panelGrid>

    </div>
```

Como faço para tira essas bordas?

Comment: Veja se a resposta dessa pergunta te ajuda. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421581/how-to-remove-border-from-specific-primefaces-ppanelgrid

Answer (score 2):

Crie um classe css:

```
.semBorda tr, .semBorda td {  
   border: none !important;  
}
```

E adicione no seu `panelGrid`.